# reordering sequential IDs

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

Newbie to Pentaho's Kettle 4.4, If I have a table with sequential ID that is not an Index, how can I step through each row and ensure this ID is sequential before it is copied to a new table?

Example: Current

```
  IDs
   1
   2
   4
   5
   6
   8
```

After ETL

```
  IDs
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the `Add Sequence` step? Looks like you just want to replace the existing ID with a transform counter that is guaranteed to be sequential, correct?

Answer (score 0):

U can use **Modified Java Script Value** step with the following code :

```
var ID = getProcessCount('r');
```